# Toy from a story about a boy and his friends who are very small and live in a tree

Tags: story-identification, character-identification, toys

[image]As a kid I had this action figure/toy of a boy with short red hair, wristbands and ankle bands. Made of leaves, as so is the rest of the clothing with a bandana on his head made of leaves with two long ones coming from it that reached down, kinda like Killer Bee's hat thing from Naruto. I have no idea what's his name or what it's from, only that it's some sort of story about him and his friends who are very small and live in a tree.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How large was it?  How many points of articulation?  Can you sketch it, or find any similar pictures?  What kind of leaves?

Comment: I have no idea how to post images in a comment, but the colours were a very bright green for the leaves and they werent of a particular plant species, It had 5 points of articulation: 2 for the shoulders for the arms to move up n down, 2 for the legs at the hips to move back and forth and One for the head to move side to side

Comment: I don't remember the size clearly, i think about as much as One of those mini Equestria girls figurines?

Comment: When were you a kid? An approximate date can help find the answer.

Comment: Around the 2010s

Comment: You need to [edit] your post to add the image. Having it will make it a lot easier for someone to find the answer.

Comment: Edited It, thank you for your help and excuse my art skills, but that's as far as i remember It. I think the guy had a shirt made of leaves too but i'm not entirely sure

Answer (score 3):

Sounds somewhat similar to [Tree Fu Tom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_Fu_Tom), though he doesn't wear a bandana that I can recall; here's an example from his toy line:

[image]

Tom's friends do live in a tree, though Tom himself doesn't live there. From wikipedia:

> In each episode, Tom comes out of his house, puts on a power belt, and runs across his lawn towards a crooked tree in the woods protected by a magic shield. Using the power belt, he performs some Tree Fu moves, jumps up, shrinks to insect size as he flies into the tree, and enters the world of Treetopolis. He is skilled in that world's magic, and often gets characters out of scrapes. Some of the characters are four of Tom's friends, Twigs, Squirmtum, Ariela, and Zigzoo. The tree's sap is shown as a glowing orange magic liquid.

The TV show ran from 2012 to 2016 (and I assume the toys would be from the same period).